# WPF binding RadioButtons IsChecked to Text property of TextBlock inside DataTemplate

Tags: wpf, binding, radio-button

I have 3 RadioButtons in my app:

[image]

```
<StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="91,206,0,24">
       <TextBlock Text="Title Language:" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="20" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,15,0" />
       <RadioButton x:Name="Rad_TitleNameRomaji" Content="Romaji" FontSize="20" Margin="0,0,10,0" Checked="TitleSettingsChanged"/>
       <RadioButton x:Name="Rad_TitleNameEnglish" Content="English"  FontSize="20" Margin="0,0,10,0" Checked="TitleSettingsChanged"/>
       <RadioButton x:Name="Rad_TitleNameJapanese" Content="Japanese"  FontSize="20" Checked="TitleSettingsChanged" />
</StackPanel>
```

There is a DataTemplate for my `ListViewItem`s:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate_ListViewItems" >
        <Grid Width="213" Height="326">
            ...
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding WhatShouldIPutHere}) />
            ...
        </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

The `ListView`'s `ItemsSource` is a `List<CustClass>`.

CustClass:

```
public class CustClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string RomajiTitle { get; set; }
    public string EnglishTitle { get; set; }
    public string JapaneseTitle { get; set; }
    ...
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Now what i want is when I checked the "English" `RadioButton`, the `Text` of the `TextBlock` inside the `DataTemplate` will be bind to `EnglishTitle`. And so for the other two.

How can i approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

three `DataTriggers` should do the trick

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate_ListViewItems" >
                <Grid Width="213" Height="326">
                    <TextBlock >
                        <TextBlock.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=Rad_TitleNameRomaji,Path=IsChecked}" Value="True" >
                                        <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding RomajiTitle}"></Setter>
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=Rad_TitleNameEnglish,Path=IsChecked}" Value="True" >
                                        <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding EnglishTitle}"></Setter>
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=Rad_TitleNameJapanese,Path=IsChecked}" Value="True" >
                                        <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding JapaneseTitle}"></Setter>
                                  </DataTrigger>
                              </Style.Triggers>
                          </Style>
                      </TextBlock.Style>
                  </TextBlock>
              </Grid>
          </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Sorry for late reply, i just tried ur suggestion. Works like a charm!